# Why is using Apache only using port 80 when other ports are configured?

Tags: apache-2.4, raspbian

I have Apache running on a debian server.
On the initial install and setup, it was running fine on `port 80`, I successfully installed an instance of Wordpress and everything was fine.

I want to reduce hammering from portscanning so I am not using port 80.

I added ports `4041` and `4045` to the `ports.conf` and that's when the problems appeared.

The `ports.conf`:

```
Listen 4041
Listen 4045

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

The file `sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:4041>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName zeus
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:4045>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName zeus
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

These are the only files that I have altered, as I have another machine acting as a web server just fine.

What I get is any attempt to access `http://<ip>:4041` retrieves the default "Successfully installed Apache" index.html and the URL reads `http://<ip>` leaving off the port direction, which is different than what I see on my working server.
[image: port 4041 root]

Then there is the problem that accessing /wordpress fails.

[image: port 4041, transition]
[image: port 4041 fails]

If I access `http://<ip>:4045` I am expecting to see my Wordpress home page, based on the assigned `DocumentRoot` but all I get is fail:
[image: port 4045 "unsafe port"?]

If I change everything back to port 80, it all works fine.

[image]

Is there a compile instance functionality that I am missing?

I am baffled.

This is the most difficulty I have ever had with Apache and I have been doing the most basic things with it for more than 15 years.

I have been fussing with this for 6 hours now. GAH!!

EDIT: 2016 12 21
[Port 4045 is in the list of UNSAFE ports for Chrome:](https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I get is any attempt to access http://:4041 retrieves the
>   default "Successfully

This is expected as the virtual host on port 4041 is configured to server content from the directory

`/var/www/html`

but to my understanding your wordpress installation is located on

`/var/www/html/wordpress`

> Then there is the problem that accessing /wordpress fails

This is also expected. When you access

`http://192.168.1.20:4045/wordpress`

the wordpress site is served as expected but what happens is that the wordpress code redirects you to

`http://192.168.1.20/wordpress`

because wordpress stores the installation URL in its database.

To fix this issue you have to fix wordpress URL's using one the way describes in the following URL:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score -1):

I guess your config is not complete/correct. The following answer [Declaring multiple ports for the same VirtualHosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/219261/declaring-multiple-ports-for-the-same-virtualhosts) seems to cover your use case